# admob on other android appstores, impressions count does not change

Tags: android, admob, opera, impressions

I have the following problem with AdMob.

My app is published on Google Play, Opera Mobile Store and GetJar. It has 30 downloads from Opera Store, 120 from GetJar but AdMob is showing and counting only the impressions and clicks made from Google Play downloads. The problem is only with the other app stores 150 downloads for the last 1 week and not a single impression counted.

Any idea is something wrong with my code or it's something else?

I have removed the **addTestDevice** method calls.

```
private AdView adView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
...
        adView = (AdView) this.findViewById(R.id.adView);
        AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();

        adView.loadAd(adRequest);
...
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
...
        if (adView != null) {
                adView.resume();
        }

        super.onResume();
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {

        if (adView != null) {
                adView.pause();
        }
        super.onPause();
}

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();

        if (adView != null) {
                adView.destroy();
        }
}

<com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView 
    android:id="@id/adView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    ads:adUnitId="ca-app-pub-*******/******"
    ads:adSize="BANNER"/>
```

Comment: updated the main post

Comment: How do you know they are not counted? Have you used separate IDs?

Comment: I have used separate IDs for each banner ad. I know because there are only 2 active downloads from Google Play and one of them is a person I know. Another of my friends downloaded it from Opera Mobile Store. The friend who downloaded it from Google Play has his "impressions" counted for that day on my AdMob dashboard. On the next day, the other friend installed the app from Opera Store. He said everything is ok, the app is working fine, the ads are showing as well. But there is absolutely nothing on my AdMob dashboard for this day.

Comment: All new "impressions" match the days new users download and install the app from Google Play. And the days I have 0 new installs from Google Play but 30+ new from other stores, there are no impressions counted at all.